# Animation set taking control

Tags: android, animation

i have been trying to implement two animationsets on my view.
every time a user clicked on the view,
the view will change its animation to the other animationset.
i have come to realize that no matter what animationset I would declare,
the view will use them all, e.g.:

what I wrote:

```
AnimationSet a = ...;
AnimationSet b = ...;
myView.startAnimation(a);
```

what trully happend:

```
AnimationSet a = ...;
AnimationSet b = ...;
myView.startAnimation(a + b);
```

how can I overcome such a thing?

Comment: You should stop the first animation and the start second animation.

Comment: if i declare two animationsets and want to use one of them, it seems i just cant

Comment: it would start them both